# Upgrading Pip in Venv Overrides Python Installation

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I made the mistake of using the --user option when upgrading pip inside of venv, and now the output of `which python` is `/usr/bin/python` when before it was `/Users/myName/myVenv/bin/python`. Now I can't just run `python` to get my desired installation. Why is this, and how can I fix it?.

The command in question:

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Running:

```
pip freeze
```

Outputs `WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper.` This seems to be because while I setup my venv with Python3, the reversion set the default back to Python2, which is the default installation on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Do you still have the virtual environment activated? Because I would think it would be the opposite if you had used the `--user` flag

Comment: Yes. I deactivated and reactivated it, and `which` still gives the same output.

Comment: Might want to try `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed python` inside the virtual environment but something seems off and if I were you I'd just `pip freeze` the dependencies and recreate the virtual environment